# Laravel 8 how do we get authenticated users email address

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get authenticated user email automatically and insert into the database table in Livewire using

`Auth::User()->email;`

but this is not working.

it shows below error
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: show the code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, this worked form me

```
public function mount()
        {
            $this->phone = Auth::user()->phone;
            $this->email = Auth::user()->email;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the user is already logged into your application, do a **[Auth::check()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated)**, this method on the **Auth** facade, which will return `true` if the user is authenticated :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    dd(Auth::user()->email);
}
```

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: it works but i want is to assign Auth::user()->email; to $email variable

public $email = Auth::user()->email;

then i get this error
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: @Chamila This is because a static variable contains a constant value in it. But in your case, `Auth::user()->email;` is dynamic that can change its value during the execution. That's why the error is showing